# BeanCreationException: autowired dependencies failed with another maven spring project

Tags: java, spring, maven, jar, autowired

I have some trouble with autowired in combination with a second spring boot project. Hopefully, you can give me some hints to fix the issue.

**Project setup:**
The project datahub manages the data store access. The project dataintegration does some other stuff but needs the project datahub to comunicate with the data store. Both projects base on spring boot and are realized as maven projects.

**Problem:**
When I try to start dataintegration project (run Application.java), where the datahub project is integrated via maven dependency, I get the exception at the end of the thread. The project datahub works as stand-alone demo application. It works also together (integrated via pom.xml as dependency) with a spring boot web application (Reading data store entities via HTTP request).

Any ideas??? The most frustrating point is that the same setup is working when the project dataintegration is realized as web application. But it isn't working when dataintegration is realized as native java application (jar).

**Datahub (com.example.mcp.datahub):**

Application.java

```
package com.example.mcp.datahub;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import com.example.mcp.datahub.model.WorkingDay;
import com.example.mcp.datahub.service.WorkingDayService;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement 
@ComponentScan("com.example.mcp")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

WorkingDayRepository.java

```
package com.example.mcp.datahub.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.mcp.datahub.model.WorkingDay;

@Repository
public interface WorkingDayRepository extends CrudRepository<WorkingDay, Long> {

}
```

WorkingDayService.java

```
package com.example.mcp.datahub.service;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.example.mcp.datahub.model.WorkingDay;
import com.example.mcp.datahub.repositories.WorkingDayRepository;

@Service
@ComponentScan("com.example.mcp")
public class WorkingDayService {

    @Autowired
    public WorkingDayRepository workingDayRepository;

    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public List<WorkingDay> getWorkingDays() {
        List<WorkingDay> list = (List<WorkingDay>) workingDayRepository.findAll();
        return list;
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example.mcp.datahub</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.example.mcp.datahub</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>com.example.mcp.datahub</name>
    <description>Data Hub</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

**Dataintegration (com.example.mcp.dataintegration):**

Application.java

```
package com.example.mcp.dataintegration;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;


@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan("com.example.mcp")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

ScheduledTasks.java

```
package com.example.mcp.dataintegration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.mcp.datahub.model.WorkingDay;
import com.example.mcp.datahub.service.WorkingDayService;

@Service
@ComponentScan("com.example.mcp")
public class ScheduledTasks {

    @Autowired 
    public WorkingDayService workingDayService;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
    public void reportCurrentTime() {
        //do something with workingDayService
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example.mcp.dataintegration</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.example.mcp.dataintegration</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>com.example.mcp.dataintegration</name>
    <description>Data Integration Layer</description>

     <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository  -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example.mcp.datahub</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.example.mcp.datahub</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Exception**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scheduledTasks': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public com.example.mcp.datahub.service.WorkingDayService com.example.mcp.dataintegration.ScheduledTasks.workingDayService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'workingDayService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public com.example.mcp.datahub.repositories.WorkingDayRepository com.example.mcp.datahub.service.WorkingDayService.workingDayRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.example.mcp.datahub.repositories.WorkingDayRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ...
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at com.example.mcp.dataintegration.Application.main(Application.java:15) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public com.example.mcp.datahub.service.WorkingDayService com.example.mcp.dataintegration.ScheduledTasks.workingDayService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'workingDayService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public com.example.mcp.datahub.repositories.WorkingDayRepository com.example.mcp.datahub.service.WorkingDayService.workingDayRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.example.mcp.datahub.repositories.WorkingDayRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'workingDayService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public com.example.mcp.datahub.repositories.WorkingDayRepository com.example.mcp.datahub.service.WorkingDayService.workingDayRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.example.mcp.datahub.repositories.WorkingDayRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
...
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public com.example.mcp.datahub.repositories.WorkingDayRepository com.example.mcp.datahub.service.WorkingDayService.workingDayRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.example.mcp.datahub.repositories.WorkingDayRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.example.mcp.datahub.repositories.WorkingDayRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ...
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Let me guess, the data integration doesn't have the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` as a dependency. Also please remove the `@ComponentScan` on the service class as that is just useless it is only useable on `@Configuration` classes.

Comment: @m-deinum: Unfortunately, I forgot the second pom.xml. Already attached. spring-boot-starter-data-jpa is available as dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already solved the problem. The following post was quite helpful: [Spring Boot And Multi-Module Maven Projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25071267/spring-boot-and-multi-module-maven-projects)

I moved the file com.example.mcp.dataintegration.Application.java to com.example.mcp.Application.java. But furthermore unclear why my ComponentScan amd JPARepo definition were ignored...

Answer (score 1):

Did you try **@EnableJpaRepositories** with **@Configuration** in Application class that you run.

I have tried something like this for one of my projects which is similar to yours and it worked for me;

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.mcp")
@EntityScan("com.example.mcp")
```

WorkingDay has **@Entity** annotation.

Comment: I added **@Configuration** and **@EnableJpaRepositories** to Application.class. Some error as before....